# How to reverse a DLL into C++ code?

Tags: c++, dll, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I know it's impossible to reverse a dll into a c++ code so I would like to collect as much as possible details from it.
It's not my dll, so I don't have the source code of course. Which program should I use?

Comment: A popular binary reverse engineering tool is IDA Pro – there's a free version, that suffice most basic needs.

Comment: Do you have some understanding of what the DLL does? How large is it? Do you know what language it was written in originally? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I added some "key phrases" as tags. Look them up.

Comment: It's definitely not "impossible". Difficult, maybe, but if you have the code, you can almost always write an equivalent source that will produce the same results. Though it may take a long time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, if you are skilled you can disassemble the DLL and understand all of its functions. This takes a substantial amount of time, but if you do that you can reverse it back to source by hand.

Otherwise, you can start by using a tool like Dependency Walker to get the DLLs and functions it depends on, and the functions it exports. From there you can find functions that interest you, and use a disassembler like IDA to see what they do.

Comment: No one, except silly people who have too much time at their hand would reverse *everything*. You'd always go with something like IDA and follow the call paths that interest you. Besides, you can see exports in IDA itself. No need for an intermediary. +1 still

Comment: Not everyone has IDA, or wants to learn it. So, I suggest Dependency Walker as a very simple way to get useful information. (Of course, if you are good at IDA, you can of course do everything there :) )

Answer (score 2):

You can see the list of exported functions by using the [dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756as972%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) tool. If C++ functions are exported, you might be able to infer parameters by the name mangling.

You can extract all the resources from the DLL by just "opening" it as a file for resource viewing in Visual Studio. If the DLL is a COM based DLL, there's a small chance the Type Library is embedded as a resource inside it.  And if you have the Type Library, you can #import it to reconstruct the header files for the public interfaces.

That's about as good as it gets.

Comment: I disagree that that's about as good as it gets - it all depends how much time/skill/effort you have available. See nneonneo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a PE file viewer. This will tell you the exports from the DLL and you can get the data in the .text section to see the machine code.